# Map Quest POI Markers Text

Tags: asp.net, markers, mapquest

I am working with existing Map Quest code, in that I am showing POIs with Alphabet labels . Like A B C and so on.

I want to replace them with 1 2 3 4 .... so on.

Is there any property that has to set before loading map or initializing.?
Like!
[image]

I want to replace A,B with 1,2

Answer (score 1):

After a little research < I figured out that, MAP Quest return a image list with link, I manually replaced the last character with my index number that is 1,2,3 or whatever